# Hx711 is outputting only zero

Tags: arduino-uno

I am strain guages in a wheatstone bridge along with hx711 . For testing amplifier I used potentiometers to change the input voltage for hx711. It is outputting only zero. Here is my code.

```
#include "HX711.h"

// HX711 circuit wiring
const int LOADCELL_DOUT_PIN = 2;
const int LOADCELL_SCK_PIN = 3;

HX711 scale;

float calibration_factor = 282650.0; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  scale.begin(LOADCELL_DOUT_PIN, LOADCELL_SCK_PIN);
  scale.set_scale();
  scale.tare(); //Reset the scale to 0
}

void loop() {
  if (scale.is_ready()) {
    long reading = scale.read();
    Serial.print("HX711 reading: ");
    //Serial.println(reading);
    Serial.println(scale.get_units(), 5);
  } else {
    Serial.println("HX711 not found.");
  }   
  delay(1000); 
}
```

Comment: calibration_factor is defined but not used?

Comment: I did add a line  scale.set_scale(calibration_factor);  in the void loop. But still it is giving zero. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome.